# Upgrading to a newer version of Cocos2dx

Tags: upgrade, cocos2d-x

I've been running cocos2dx version 1.0.1-x-0.11.0 till now and have a small project working fine. I need to upgrade to the latest version, cocos2d-2.0-x-2.0.4. What would be the correct way to do this? I don't want to 
A. Mess up my project. 
B. End up with 2 different versions of cocos2dx

Can I just download and replace the old cocos2dx folder with the new one? Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Edit:
I actually downloaded the latest version and tried to set it up separately. I ran the build_win32.bat and after running for a while it opened the test application. Then I opened the vs2010.sln and tried adding a new project, but it throws include errors.

```
Error   3   error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'CCApplication.h': No such file or directory c:\cocos2d-2.0-x-2.0.4\chilra\classes\appdelegate.h 4   1   Chilra.win32
Error   2   error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'CCPlatformDefine.h': No such file or directory  c:\cocos2d-2.0-x-2.0.4\cocos2dx\platform\ccplatformmacros.h 32  1   Chilra.win32
Error   1   error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'CCStdC.h': No such file or directory    c:\cocos2d-2.0-x-2.0.4\chilra\win32\main.h  11  1   Chilra.win32
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. X:\CC2Dx (where my source is, unzipped the entire source file into this folder)
2. Open the cocs2d-Win32.sln. Run it in Debug mode and Release mode, You should find Debug.win32, Release.win32 folder inside your cocos2d-x 
       (Now here you can test, Make TestCpp as startupProject by RightClicking on the folder TestCpp ..then Run)
3. Now Run build_win32.bat  (It will copy some files in to your Debug.win32 and Release.win32

This is where it created the solution, Debug.win32 & Release.win32.

1. After running build_win32.bat now either you can create your new project using VS 2008 template because Vs2012 has some script error I have solution for that also 
   But I suggest you to copy the HelloWorldProject and replace it with your files
2. Always Remember whenever you get some cocos2d file error like you have got in your above procedure then just copy those .lib file and .dll files from the Debug.win32 and Release.win32
   and then run ......

This works fine

Any queries please feel free to ask

Comment: to fix template errors you have to "unblock" two template files with explorer:
cocos2d-1.0.1-x-0.11.0\template\msvc\CCAppWiz.win32\HTML\1033\default.htm
cocos2d-1.0.1-x-0.11.0\template\msvc\CCAppWiz.win32\HTML\1033\features.htm

Right click on the files, select "Properties" and click on "Unblock" at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

I've added cocos2dx to the upstream tracker for analysis and seems there some API/ABI changes made between 0.11.0 and 2.0.4: http://upstream.rosalinux.ru/versions/cocos2d-x.html

[image]

You can use [japi-compliance-checker](https://github.com/lvc/japi-compliance-checker) tool to generate such reports.